# Oracle doesn't push predicate when joining 2 table

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I encountered a problem which **Oracle does not perform push predicate**, making query slow.

Here are the examples explaining the situation:

```
-- Pushed predicate 
SELECT *
FROM my_view v, my_table t
WHERE v.col1 = t.col1
  AND t.col2 LIKE 'abc%'

-- No pushed predicate
SELECT *
FROM my_view v, my_table_1 t1, my_table_2 t2
WHERE v.col1  = t1.col1
  AND t1.col2 LIKE 'abc%'
  AND v.col2  = t2.col1
```

**For the 1st query, the optimizer will push the `v.col1 = t.col1` predicate to the view.** More, as the column `v.col1` has an index, the index would be used, avoiding FULL table scan.

**However, push predicate is NOT performed in the 2nd query.** The only difference between the above query and the first query is that one more table is being joined. But, in this case, Oracle does not push the `v.col1  = t1.col1` predicate to the view and FULL SCAN the (backing table of) the view, which then make the query very slow.

I would be very grateful if someone would give me some suggestions about this or viable solutions.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably not useful, but `v.col1  = t1.col1` and `v.col2  = t2.col1` seem to be joins - have you tried `JOINing` these as opposed to `WHERE`?

Comment: Please tag your question appropiately, is it `sql` or `oracle`? As @StuartLC is saying, please also don't use Old-style joins: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @NickyvV This is  a question about Oracle. Sorry, the tags have been updated. Thanks for reminding. For the style of joins, this is a query dynamically generated by a system actually, so I don't think I could do anything to this. But, again, thanks for kindly reminding me.

Comment: @NickyvV: the tag `sql` **is** applicable here the tag `sql` is for the query language, not for any specific DBMS product. If you are thinking about SQL Server, there is a tag for that: `sql-server` - SQL and SQL Server are two different things.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I also saw that when the OP commented. Sorry 'bout that :)